# How to write a JSON file on internal storage

Tags: android

I would like to write json file on internal storage but I can not handle it. Here is my code:

```
String answers_json = data.getExtras().getString("answers");
            Log.d("****", "****************** WE HAVE ANSWERS ******************");
            Log.v("ANSWERS JSON", answers_json);
            Log.d("****", "*****************************************************");

            try {
                File file = new File (getFilesDir(),"answers.json");
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                writer.write("answers");
                writer.flush();
                writer.close()
```

I have tried so many variants, but it ends always with an error "open failed" or whenever everything is fine, no file finds on my phone (that means nothing happened). What is wrong on my side?

Comment: Where are you saving that file? ;)

Comment: File file = new File (getFilesDir(),"answers.json"); is it better?

Comment: ok, thank you very much. i try to figure it out. you helped me a lot. there are many tutorials but nothing specific :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. But you did not tell how you tried to find the file or how you checked if it existed. Your file is saved in private internal memory.

Comment: Log the value of file.getAbsolutePath() and tell us.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. This is working for me...

```
            try {
                String FILENAME = "answers.json";
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                assert answers_json != null;
                fos.write(answers_json.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

greets and thank for your help.

Answer (score -1):

This may help you:

```
 private void downloadAndStoreJson(String url,String tag){

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);          

    String jsonString = json.toString();                
    byte[] jsonArray = jsonString.getBytes();

    File fileToSaveJson = new File("/sdcard/appData/LocalJson/",tag);



    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    try {
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileToSaveJson));
        bos.write(jsonArray);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e4.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        jsonArray=null;
        jParser=null;
        System.gc();
    }}
```

Comment: `"/sdcard/appData/LocalJson/"` <= bad idea